# Como configurar um projeto no Git e GitHub?

Tags: git, github

Possuo um [projeto](https://github.com/drmcarvalho/ProdRegex) no GitHub chamado `ProdRegex` ele não contem arquivo algum, tenho o projeto salvo em meu PC no seguinte caminho `~/Projetos C/Feichas Aula/ProjetoProdRegex` onde esta todos os arquivos do projeto, e já instalei o **git** em minha maquina, porem não sei como configurar o projeto na minha maquina para sincronizar com minha conta  no **GitHub**. Fiz uma pesquisa mais mesmo assim to tendo dificuldade em fazer esta configuração, se alguém poder me ajudar desde já agradeço.

Comment: qual git client está usando? exemplo: Sourcetree

Comment: Estou te seguindo lá ;)

Comment: to seguindo de volta :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[O GitHub tem um aplicativo](https://desktop.github.com/), mais simples que configurar o Git nativo e usar.

Basicamente, é só instalar e vincular sua conta do GitHub nele.

Haverá nele 3 opções: **Add**, **Create** e **Clone**:

- **Add**: Adiciona um repositório local a ele. Sendo um repositório ligado remotamente ao GitHub, permite sincronizar com o GitHub;
- **Create**: Cria um repositório local novo. Depois há a opção **Publish**, em que você sobe este repositório para o GitHub na sua conta;
- **Clone**: Clona um repositório do GitHub para sua máquina. No seu caso, seria esta a primeira opção a usar.

Lembrando que a opção **Commit** não envia dados para o GitHub. As opções que fazem isso são **Publish** (quando o repositório não existe) e **Sync** (quando o repositório já existe). A opção **Commit** apenas salva o estado daquele repositório, permitindo a você reverter facilmente as modificações se assim desejar.

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta.